# Why do my quick edits for custom taxonomies not show on the post frontend?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields, quick-edit

So I have created a couple of custom taxonomies and to save time I used the quick edit to apply taxonomy terms to posts. The problem is these changes don't show on the frontend.

When I go in to edit these posts I can see the values I applied in quick edit on the backend but when I go to the frontend they are not there.

They only appear when I manually go into the post and save it.

Any ideas why this is happening or how I can push through the quick edit change?

Comment: Are you using some sort of cache plugin? Or does your host provide some kind of page cache?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Nope all caching is displayed and I have tried purging multiple times to make sure but definitely not a caching issue.